# Jwplayer fails to run

Tags: jquery, video, jwplayer

I have tried to implement a JWPlayer as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var divid= document.getElementById("mediaplayerid").getAttribute("id");
         alert(divid);
         jwplayer(divid).setup({
             flashplayer: "http://www.jeroenwijering.com/embed/player.swf",
             provider: "video",
             file: "Videos/2.mp4",
             autostart: false,
         });
     });
</script>
```

Where i have taken a div tag in a table as:

```
<tr>
    <td class="style3" style="width: 50%"></td>
    <td class="style3" style="width: 50%">           
        <div id="mediaplayerid"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JWPlayer fails to run. I have debugged the script. It reaches to a point Jwplayer.setup after it that comes out with no output. What possibly be an error or any code error.

Comment: What if you use it like this `jwplayer("mediaplayerid").setup({stuff here...});`? Does it work this way?

Comment: @alone evenings No sir, i have tried that.

Comment: I think you are forgetting to set width and height. Try setting width and height.

Comment: What happens if you try jwplayer('mediaplayerid').setup(...  ?
also, remove the trailing comma from the setup set after autostart:false

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the div id as a string to jwplayer setup. Try replacing `jwplayer(divid)` with `jwplayer('mediaplayerid')`.

Here is the complete code:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            jwplayer('mediaplayerid').setup({
                flashplayer: "http://www.jeroenwijering.com/embed/player.swf",
                provider: "video",
                file: "Videos/2.mp4",
                autostart: false,
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="mediaplayerid"></div>
```

Also, I don't think that particular player is working correctly for what I could test. I would recommend getting the last version from [Longtail's website](http://www.longtailvideo.com/). They have a nice [setup wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/wizard/) you can use to create the embed code you need.